# Convert Enum into Flow with elixir

Tags: elixir

I have 2 million data file to process.
Following code takes 2 hours to work done.

```
out_file = "./output.tsv"
result = "./input.tsv"
         |> File.stream!
         |> CSV.decode(separator: ?\t, headers: headers)
         |> Enum.map(&(elem(&1, 1)))
         |> Enum.group_by(&{&1.id, &1.name})
         |> Enum.map(&(format_data(&1)))
File.write(out_file, result)
```

in order to proceed with high performance, I've taken with `Flow`, then I wrote following code.
It seems like `Enum`, so I simply added `Flow.from_enumerable`,  then rewrote `Enum` into `Flow`.

```
out_file = "./output.tsv"
result = "./input.tsv"
         |> File.stream!
         |> CSV.decode(separator: ?\t, headers: headers)
         |> Flow.from_enumerable(stages: 4)
         |> Flow.map(&(elem(&1, 1)))
         |> Flow.group_by(&{&1.id, &1.name})
         |> Flow.map(&(format_data(&1)))
File.write(out_file, result)
```

It does not work. I don't think right way to use `Flow` like this.
Please let me know your advice to correct use of `Flow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very top example on the main documentation page of [`Flow`](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html#module-example) shows that you have to terminate `Flow` as well as `Stream` with somewhat like `Enum.to_list()`.

In your first snippet the termination happens on the first call to `Enum.map/2` (`Stream.map/2` and family is to be used for stream processing, `File.stream!/1` there acts the same as `Fire.read/1` because you immediately terminate it.)

Also, [`NimbleCSV`](https://hexdocs.pm/nimble_csv) was explicitly created by Elixir core team to stream-process CSVs. Anyway, below would probably work:

```rb
result =
  "./input.tsv"
  |> File.stream!
  # here the stream is terminated
  |> CSV.decode(separator: ?\t, headers: headers)
  |> Flow.from_enumerable(stages: 4)
  |> Flow.map(&(elem(&1, 1)))
  |> Flow.group_by(&{&1.id, &1.name})
  |> Flow.map(&(format_data(&1)))
  # ⇓ THIS IS IMPORTANT
  |> Enum.to_list()
```

The better approach would be:

```rb
result =
  "./input.tsv"
  |> File.stream!(read_ahead: 100_000)
  |> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream()
  |> Flow.from_enumerable(stages: 4)
  |> Flow.map(&(elem(&1, 1)))
  |> Flow.group_by(&{&1.id, &1.name})
  |> Flow.map(&(format_data(&1)))
  # ⇓ THIS IS IMPORTANT
  |> Enum.to_list()
```